# How to see the oiginal data via decrypt in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I encrypted my password field and inserted it into a MySQL table. 
After that I decrypted that column by

```
select fld_user,fld_pwd,AES_DECRYPT(fld_encryptedpwd,'key')
  from users 
 where fld_id='1903';
```

But, the result is showing "BLOB". I used Varbinary() as the datatype for encrypted column. What I should do ?

Comment: You don't mention 'where' it showing it as BLOB. Which MySQL version?

Comment: Also, you should not use AES_ENCRYPT() to store password. You should use a one-way hashing like at least SHA-1. Encrypting is little worse than just storing it plain text once folks get the key.

Comment: @geertjanvdk BLOB is shown in my output field, I could not use One way hashing. Because, Sometimes I need to decrypt the password field

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean with 'output field' and where this is shown. What tool are you using?

Comment: @geertjanvdk I'm using MySQL workbench. While i'm execute the query "select fld_user,fld_pwd,AES_DECRYPT(fld_encryptedpwd,'key')
from users where fld_id='1903';" it is returning BLOB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution for in MySQL Workbench is to toggle the following option for the SQL Editor: "Treat BINARY/VARBINARY as nonbinary character string." At least on MacOS X, you'll need to restart Workbench for the option to take effect. (You can also right click the value and do 'Open Value in Viewer').

If you don't want to change the options in Workbench, you can use the [CAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html) function to return the result of [AES_DECRYPT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html) as a string:

```
SELECT fld_user, fld_pwd, CAST(AES_DECRYPT(fld_encryptedpwd, 'key') AS CHAR)
FROM users WHERE fld_id='1903';
```

A trick to check/make sure what data type a function would return is to do the following using the MySQL CLI:

```
mysql> CREATE TALBE tmp1 AS SELECT AES_DECRYPT(fld_encryptedpwd, 'key')
       FROM users WHERE fld_id='1903';
mysql> DESC tmp1;
```

That will show which data type will be returned.

(Again, storing encrypted passwords: not so good.)

Comment: The tmp1 table the password stored as BLOB. I need to get my original password. My original password is 'test123'

Comment: @geertjanvdk Cast is working fine.what is the purpose of CAST() ?

Comment: May I suggest you read about MySQL Data Types? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-types.html

Comment: @user1346409 Quoted from the MySQL manual: "The CAST() function takes an expression of any type and produces a result value of a specified type."

Comment: I have now completed the answer with multiple solutions in Workbench and using SQL, using the CAST() thus.